# WebAPI approach to programmatically access a shared folder in a network path C#

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I have hosted WebAPI application on IIS server of windows server 2008 R2, which needs to access shared folder directory on a network path (`\\servername\foldername`) that is on another server.

I have enabled full permission on that folder for all users (everyone). But my webAPI is unable to access that shared folder.
I see Server.MapPath is not a part of web API and that there is a class system.web.hosting which implements `HostingEnvironment.MapPath(network path string)`, tut this is just making the virtual to physical path and finally makes hosting environment as the root folder which is not what I require. I want to access shared folder on another server.

FYI the remote shared folder is in the same network domain.
Please help me how i can achieve it in C# and .NET 4.5 (not later than this)

Comment: What about accessing the folder via FTP server?

Comment: Harsh, I am not looking for FTP server.